# firestore nested object field needs updating, not replacing

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app, where announcements are shown, stored in firestore and with that there is a hasRead object for each announcement.
It works, as in when a user is reading the announcement it is shown as read on the users app. But when another user is reading the same announcement, his/her usrid is being stored, overwriting the any other usrid stored.

Here his how I store it.

```
setAnnounceToRead(userId) {
    firebase.firestore().collection('announcements').doc(this.state.id).set({
        hasread: {
            userId
        }
    },
    { merge: true });
}
```

I already found out that it is because of the merge, as it doesn't "adds" the usrid but overrides it instead.

How can I add every userid that reads the announcement, but keeping the already existing userids?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're storing each user's UID as a field named `userId`. Since you're using the same field name for each user, you end up storing only the last user's UID.

To store the UID for all users, you'd usually have a structure like this:

```
hasread: {
    udartsUid: true,
    pufsUid: true
}
```

In your code that would translate to something like:

```
let update = {};
update[userId] = true;
firebase.firestore().collection('announcements').doc(this.state.id).set({
    hasread: update
},
{ merge: true });
```

But this type of operation got a lot easier recently, since Firestore now has operations that allow you to use an array for this type of information.

```
let doc = firebase.firestore().collection('announcements').doc(this.state.id);
doc.update({ "hasRead": FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId) });
```

This snippets will add the `userId` value to the array if it isn't already in there. If the value is already in the array, it does nothing.

For more on the latter, see the blog post [Better arrays in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html).

Comment: thanks, will have a look as soon as I can and will let you know.

Comment: I am using react-native-firebase and it seems that the FieldValue is not yet supported there.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like that library hasn't been updated yet: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/85321b5246fc313b409116617d19636ab3029adf/src/modules/firestore/FieldValue.js#L6

Comment: yes indeed, so until that has been updated, I should use your first example, correct?